# How can I use a list of variables to create sql query string?

Tags: python, string

I tried using the code below, but i still have the ' ' around each element in the string.

```
l = ['a','b','c']
query = "SELECT " + str(l).strip('[,]') + " FROM table"
```

returns

```
"SELECT 'a', 'b', 'c' FROM table"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [How would you make a comma-separated string from a list of strings?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44778) (Not hammering as dupe because this is SQL and building SQL commands from variables is probably bad)

Comment: I have txt file with a list of variables. What would the preferred way to build the query? @Aran-Fey

Comment: use a library like `pypika`

Comment: Did you check what does strip() do first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.join`:

```
query = "SELECT " + ", ".join(l) + " FROM table"

print(query)

"SELECT a, b, c FROM table"
```

As pointed out, forming SQL queries from strings should be a last resort.

Comment: This is only safe if you are *positive* that `l` actually contains only valid columns names. (Also, it returns the same string the OP already has.)

Comment: @chepner, Yep. We're making several assumptions, e.g. `table` exists, the column list reflects valid `table` fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can use join :-

```
l = ['a','b','c']
query = "SELECT '" + l.join('') + "' FROM table"

print(query)

"SELECT 'abc' FROM table"
```

if you want them to join you can use the above code.